# Stop function evaluating input at time of definition

Tags: functions

I would like to create a function that acts on whether the input is even or odd, e.g.:

```
In[644]:= f[a_] = If[EvenQ[a], 2 a, 3 a];
          f[2]

Out[645]= 6
```

I've determined (I think) that this is because `a` is an expression and `QEven` returns false for expressions. How do I hold off evalution of this until input is given? I thought something like `Defer` would work but then it is never evaluated (see below)!

```
In[641]:= g[a_] = If[Defer[EvenQ[a]], 2 a, 3 a]

Out[641]= If[EvenQ[a], 2 a, 3 a]

In[643]:= g[3]

Out[643]= If[EvenQ[3], 2 * 3, 3 * 3]
```

Apologies if this gets asked a lot - I assume this is a common issue, but I was unable to come up with appropriate search terms to describe it (I'm not very familiar with Mathematica terminology yet). Thanks!

Comment: You need to `SetDelayed` instead of `Set`. `f[a_] := ...`

Comment: Brilliant thanks, that thread looks very useful. It should have been my first port of call!

Answer (score 0):

```
fun[x_?EvenQ] := 2 x
fun[x_?OddQ] := 3 x
```

Non-integer arguments will just return the fun[arg].

`fun[2]` yields 4 and `fun[3]`  yields 9.